# jquery + json load content but show errors in firebug console

Tags: jquery, json, firebug

now i can load json content for 3 different sections in webpage, but show several errors passing content by variables in functions. I explain.

1st section use jquery function to load content from file1.json.

script for 1st section

```
var f = $(this).data('residentidx');
$.getJSON("file1.json", function(data) {
    $("#tt_mn").html($("<p class='prod_c'>" + data.articles[f].title + "</p>"));
    $("#content_mn").html($("<p class='prod_d'>" + data.articles[f].esquema + "</p>"));
});
```

file1.json

```
{"articles":
[{"title":"......", "esquema":"............"}, ...,{"title":".....","esquema":"......"}]}
```

script por 2nd section

```
var i = $(this).data('renovidx');
$.getJSON("file2.json", function(data) {
    $("#tt_mn").html($("<p class='prod_c'>" + data.articles[i].title + "</p>"));
    $("#content_mn").html($("<p class='prod_d'>" + data.articles[i].esquema + "</p>"));
});
```

file2.json

```
{"articles":
[{"title":"......", "esquema":"............"}, ...,{"title":".....","esquema":"......"}]}
```

all seems to be ok infact data shows correctly but it shows errors in firebug console.

```
data.articles[i] is undefined @ http://www.xxxxx.com/js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js:14
```

it's strange because firebug console show error for [i] value when I'm in 2nd section in which jquery-function use [f] value to find elements in json array.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

did you validate your JSON ? use http://jsonlint.com/   or for html  http://json.bloople.net/

Answer (score 0):

The second function you show is using the `i` variable, which would explain why it's throwing the error at that point...

Have you checked to see what `$(this).data('renovidx')` is returning? Are you sure you have a JSON key value pair with a key that equals `$(this).data('renovidx')`?

Comment: 1st section has a submenu with 8 titles, when i click in each titles, it load script. It could be best if i write 1 function for each section. Now I repeat the same code in html for each 8 options. But i dont understand you when you say if i've checked to see what $(this).data('renovidx') is returning. ¿?

Comment: You're using the value returned from `var i = $(this).data('renovidx');` (presumably you have a "data-revovidx" parameter on each submenu item) to get a value out of your JSON response: `data.articles[i].title` but if your JSON doesn't include a key that matches whatever the value of `var i` is, it would throw a `undefined` error.

Comment: 8 items in submenu (keys 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7). Could it be a problem NOT to make one function loaded in the head of document which it could be loaded only when i call it in a item event??? Curiously, when i'm in a section that uses [i] key, it shows error for [f] key that it wasnt loaded yet.....

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean by your last comment. Would you be able to update your code you original posted to show the click event that triggers the AJAX call?